# Swift protocol with associated type - type may not reference itself as a requirement

Tags: swift, protocols, protocol-op

I have the following protocol and its extension

```
public protocol RESEndpointReachable: CustomDebugStringConvertible
{
    associatedtype EndpointType: RESEndpointReachable


    //  MARK: - Properties

    /// The name of the endpoint as defined in the REST URI.
    var name: String { get }

    /// An array of possible next endpoints that this endpoint can reach. E.g account's next endpoints would be authenticate and unauthenticate.
    var nextPossibleEndpoints: [EndpointType] { get }


    //  MARK: - Ability

    /// Used to process the endpoint.
    func processRequest(request: RERequest)

    /// Processes the next endpoint that matches the name `name`. Expects an endpoint with the name `name` to exist in `nextPossibleEndpoints`.
    func processNextEndpointWithName(name: String, request: RERequest)
}

public extension RESEndpointReachable
{
    //  MARK: - CustomDebugStringConvertible

    public var debugDescription: String {
        return name
    }


    //  MARK: - RESEndpointReachable

    var nextPossibleEndpoints: [EndpointType] {
        return []
    }

    public func processRequest(request: RERequest)
    {
        //  Check all possible endpoints are being processed
        if let nextEndpoint = nextPossibleEndpoints.first
        {
            fatalError("Unhandled endpoint \(nextEndpoint).")
        }
    }

    public func processNextEndpointWithName(name: String, request: RERequest)
    {
        //  Get the next endpoint that matches the specified name
        let nextEndpoints = nextPossibleEndpoints.filter { $0.name == name }

        if nextEndpoints.count > 1
        {
            fatalError("Multiple next endpoints found with the name '\(name)'.")
        }

        guard let nextEndpoint = nextEndpoints.first else
        {
            fatalError("No next endpoint with the name '\(name)'.")
        }


        //  Process the next endpoint
        nextEndpoint.processRequest(request)
    }
}
```

On building, the line `associatedtype EndpointType: RESEndpointReachable` has the following error: `Type may not reference itself as a requirement`. But as I understand it this is how you use associated types in Swift.

As you may have guessed, I always want whatever `EndpointType` ends up being set as to be a type that inherits from `RESEndpointReachable`.

Comment: I don't this feature is possible right now! Ref: https://gist.github.com/curtclifton/1923a47774a94e904bf0 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15256. It will make compiler run in recursive loops

Comment: Thanks :) I thought that might be the case… Maybe next month...

Comment: This feature is available now in Swift 4.1. Got to know about it here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/50/whats-new-in-swift-4-1

Answer (score 4):

This feature is referred to by the Swift team as 'recursive protocol constraints', and is on the roadmap to be added in a future version of Swift. For more information about this and other planned features, check out the Swift team's ['Completing Generics' manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md).

Comment: Seems ridiculous to me, that Swift 4 still doesn't support this -.-

Comment: According to Doug Gregor's comment in the issue tracking this (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1445), it was released with Swift 4.1, so the latest Xcode _should_ ship with a compiler that supports it. (Haven't tried it myself, so I don't know how well the feature works in practice...)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that is not OK with swift. A protocol can't use it self as a type constraint. One solution is to declare an extra protocol that **RESEndpointReachable** itself will adopt and constraint **RESEndpointReachable** to that super protocol.

I took the example from the book **iOS 10 Programming Fundamentals with Swift** by Neuburg M. (please see page 194)

illegal example:

```
  1 protocol Flier {
  2         associatedtype Other : Flier
  3         func flockTogetherWith(_ f: Other)
  4 }
  5 
  6 struct Bird : Flier {
  7         func flockTogetherWith(_ f: Bird) {}
  8 }
```

Solution:

```
  1 protocol Superflier {}
  2 protocol Flier: Superflier {
  3         associatedtype Other : Superflier
  4         func flockTogetherWith(_ f: Other)
  5 }       
  6 
  7 struct Bird : Flier {
  8         func flockTogetherWith(_ f: Bird) {}
  9 }
```

Cheers